# TensorFlow fake-quantize layers are also called from TF-Lite

Tags: tensorflow, quantization, tensorflow-lite, quantization-aware-training

I'm using TensorFlow 2.1 in order to train models with quantization-aware training.

The code to do that is:

```
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_model(model)
```

This will add fake-quantize nodes to the graph. These nodes should adjust the model's weights so they are more easier to be quantized into int8 and to work with int8 data.

When the training ends, I convert and quantize the model to TF-Lite like so:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = [give data provider]
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

At this point, I wouldn't expect to see the fake-quantize layers in the TL-Lite graph. But surprisingly, I do see them.
Moreover, when I run this quantized model in TF-Lite C++ [sample app](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal/minimal.cc), I see that it's also running the fake-quantize nodes during inference. In addition to that, it also dequantize and quantize the activations between each layer.

That's a sample of the output from the C++ code:

> Node   0 Operator Builtin Code  80 FAKE_QUANT
>     Inputs: 1
>     Outputs: 237
>   Node   1 Operator Builtin Code 114 QUANTIZE
>     Inputs: 237
>     Outputs: 238
>   Node   2 Operator Builtin Code   3 CONV_2D
>     Inputs: 238 59 58
>     Outputs: 167
>     Temporaries: 378
>   Node   3 Operator Builtin Code   6 DEQUANTIZE
>     Inputs: 167
>     Outputs: 239
>   Node   4 Operator Builtin Code  80 FAKE_QUANT
>     Inputs: 239
>     Outputs: 166
>   Node   5 Operator Builtin Code 114 QUANTIZE
>     Inputs: 166
>     Outputs: 240
>   Node   6 Operator Builtin Code   3 CONV_2D
>     Inputs: 240 61 60
>     Outputs: 169

So I find all this very weird, taking also into account the fact that this model should run only on int8 and actually fake-quantize nodes are getting float32 as inputs.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your performance comparable with the non-quantized model? Meaning, maybe the fake nodes do not matter?

Answer (score 0):

representative_dataset is mostly used with post-training quantization.

Comparing your commands with QAT example, you probably want to remove that line .

https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_example

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(q_aware_model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()


# Create float TFLite model.
float_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
float_tflite_model = float_converter.convert()

# Measure sizes of models.
_, float_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.tflite')
_, quant_file = tempfile.mkstemp('.tflite')

with open(quant_file, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(quantized_tflite_model)

with open(float_file, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(float_tflite_model)

print("Float model in Mb:", os.path.getsize(float_file) / float(2**20))
print("Quantized model in Mb:", os.path.getsize(quant_file) / float(2**20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force TF Lite to only use the INT operations:

```py
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
```

If an error occurs, then some layers of your network do not have an INT8 implementation yet.

Furthermore you could also try to investigate your network using [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron).

Nonetheless, if you also want to have INT8 inputs and output you also need to adjust those:

```
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
```

However, there is currently an open issue regarding the in- and output, see [Issue #38285](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38285)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't remove the fake-quantize layers from the graph and they are still called during inference.

Comment: Hi Meir, did you find a solution yet? If so, could you add it to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. In my case, the quantized tflite model's size increases by ~3x with fake quantization. Does it occur to you? Inspecting the tflite graph in Netron shows quantization layers are inserted between every ops.

My workaround so far is to initiate a new copy of the model without fake quantization, and then load the weights by layers from the quantization-aware-trained model. It can't directly set weights to the whole model because fake quantization layers have parameters, too.